# Logic behind Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, options

I find `VertexLabels -> "Name"` a strange setting to achieve graph nodes labeled by their index: 
`Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`. What is the logic behind this option value?

---

[image: FieldGraphZ18]

---

Comment: Would you prefer the plural seen here, `Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` ?

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley: I just find `"Name"` an odd way to specify that option. Not singular vs. plural, but just why `"Name"` rather than something more descriptive, such as `"ByIndex`".

Comment: @joseph-orourke if `"ByIndex"` was available I'd assume it would give me the index of each vertex, whereas `"Name"` gives the value (?) of the vertex. So if the vertices are images then `"Name"` will show the image, which I think is desirable. IMO it should be plural, mess up everytime on that.

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley: I see. Did not think (or know) that nodes could be images. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on comment, the `VertexLables->"Name"` option shows the "value" of each vertex:

```
{a, b, c} = {ExampleData[RandomChoice[ExampleData["TestImage"]]], 1, "c vertex"}
```

[image]

Note the use of `ImagePadding` to ensure the `VertexLabels` are not clipped.

```
Graph[{a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

**Opinion**

I find it confusing that `"Name"` is used rather than the plural, but this is nothing compared to the requirement to tinker with `ImagePadding` when using this option.